# To find angular frequency and wave vector for time series data using minimum variance method

Tags: math, statistics, data-analysis, physics

Suppose, I have 10 set of time series data velocity components Vx, Vy and Vz with 5 minutes interval of time, how to find the angular frequency and wave vector using minimum variance method for those data? Thanks!

What else method we can follow to find the angular frequency and wave vector using those time series data?

Actually, I don't understand the basic. But I was trying to use chat gpt that suggested to follow the following steps.

Stack the velocity components from all the sets to create a 3D array.
Compute the covariance matrix of the stacked velocity components.
Calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the covariance matrix.
Use the eigenvector corresponding to the minimum eigenvalue as the direction of the wave vector.
The angular frequency can be obtained from the eigenvalue corresponding to the minimum eigenvector.

I request for more clear explanation so that I can understand the basic. Thanks!

Comment: Hi! So today you learned that the text-generation tool called ChatGPT sucks at mathematical pedagogy and is not suited to be a math teacher.

Comment: I imagine all your vectors (Vx, Vy, Vz) are more or less in the same plane; what you need to do is find the plane that best goes through these vectors. The wavevector is orthogonal to that plane. When you take the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the matrix whose rows are these vectors, you should expect three eigenvalues (and three associated vectors); one of these three eigenvalues will be close to 0, and the corresponding eigenvector will be orthogonal to the plane; the other two eigenvalues should be in the same order of magnitude as your vectors, and together they form a basis of the plane

Comment: (Note that this question might get better answers on https://physics.stackexchange.com or https://stats.stackexchange.com as the people there will be more familiar with these concepts)

Comment: hanks @Stef. I have eigen values :

eigen_values = [0.001 0 0; 0 2.90 0; 0 0 13.69]; eigen_vector = [-0.0001 0.97 -0.22; 0.70 0.16 0.69; -0.70 0.16 0.69];

Then how should I get the wave vector (k) and it's components (k_mx, k_my, k_mz)? Thanks a lot!